# How to install Bluetooth on Windows 10 With No Device Manager Bluetooth Icon But Bluetooth Devices show up

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

This is the second time I have lost Bluetooth on Windows 10 on a Lenovo laptop. I have peripherals that show up on the Bluetooth settings screen, wireless headphones and and LG cell phone. The description by each of these devices says Bluetooth is turned off. I checked that the Bluetooth services are all running.

However, most the the instructions on the web are not applicable to my situation, because there is no -- I have no -- Bluetooth icon in Device Manager from which I could re-install a driver.

The last time this happened putting the Bluetooth Support service into automatic start fixed the problem. This time, all the Bluetooth services were running. I also rebooted, but that did not fix the problem.

To repeat, I have no Bluetooth icon in Device Manager, and no way I know of to install any Windows Bluetooth driver even with both my cell phone and wireless headphones showing up as Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Are we talking about a laptop? Because if the device manager doesn’t show anything, the Bluetooth adapter is simply not present.

Comment: @Daniel B It's a Lenovo laptop, which I see has problems. I've updated the OP.

Comment: I performed an Update in Lenovo Vantage, which is the new integrated with Windows 10 application that supersedes Lenovo Settings. I searched for updates, accepted them, and, after successful update, Bluetooth started working again. The only unique updates I noticed were for Intel. I was also prompted for flashing the BIOS.